# Google Enterprise Email alias, forwarding to multiple accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'd like to set-up `support@domain.com` as an alias, and have that forward to multiple accounts.

It seems like I can associate an alias with one account - but is there a way to associate it with multiple?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to setup a groupe and setup automatic forward emails from support@domain.com to group@domain.com

Comment: Would `support@domain.com` need to be a full-fledged user, and not a (free) alias?